# Flask debug in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, flask

I am running a Flask webpage on a amazon ec2 server, and for some reason the debugger is not working. I have "app.debug = True" written but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I am getting an internal server error but it is not telling me any of the debugging information. Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you won't be able to properly debug the Flask Application whilst it is operating in a Production environment (in your case whilst it is hosted on an Amazon EC2 server).

If you would like to make use of Werkzerug's interactive debugger you'll need to run the application locally on your own machine to be able to debug it.

However if you would like to receive logged errors whilst operating in a Production Environment via email, I would suggest creating a SMTPHandler and adding it to the Logger class which is attached to app.logger. See a snippet below of the ProductionConfig class which is taken from Miguel Grinberg's sample Flask application on Github. See the folder [here:](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky)

```
class ProductionConfig(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')

    @classmethod
    def init_app(cls, app):
        Config.init_app(app)

        # Email errors to the administrators
        import logging
        from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
        credentials = None
        secure = None
        if getattr(cls, 'MAIL_USERNAME', None) is not None:
            credentials = (cls.MAIL_USERNAME, cls.MAIL_PASSWORD)
            if getattr(cls, 'MAIL_USE_TLS', None):
                secure = ()
        mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
            mailhost=(cls.MAIL_SERVER, cls.MAIL_PORT),
            fromaddr=cls.FLASKY_MAIL_SENDER,
            toaddrs=[cls.FLASKY_ADMIN],
            subject=cls.FLASKY_MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX + ' Application Error',
            credentials=credentials,
            secure=secure)
        mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
```